# ¿"Países miembro" o "países miembros"?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, adjetivos, sustantivos, plurales

Estoy leyendo [un documento](https://www.cni.es/comun/recursos/descargas/OR-ASIP-02-02_03_Orientaciones_para_la_Instruccion_de_Seguridad_del_Personal.pdf) en el que se habla tanto de *países miembro* como de *estados miembros*. Ejemplo al respecto de la Agencia Espacial Europea:

> "Este organismo internacional es un consorcio [...] con el fin de impulsar la industria espacial en los **países miembro**. La ESA clasifica sus propias materias y sus **estados miembros** cuentan con una ANS para la protección de su información clasificada."

El caso es que ninguna de las dos forma me resulta extraña al oírla, al igual que ocurre con *palabras clave* y *palabras claves*. Tal vez esta segunda forma esté menos acostumbrado a escucharla. Pero ¿cuál de las dos es la correcta?

Si busco los términos directamente en Google me salen:

- "Estados miembros": 6.050.000 resultados.
- "Estados miembro": 171.000 resultados.

Con *países miembros* y *países miembro* también hay muchos más resultados para la primera opción. Sin embargo, tanto *miembro* como *clave* no son adjetivos, sino sustantivos. ¿Es necesaria entonces la concordancia de número?

Comment: La respuesta que buscas http://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas, cuando tenga tiempo elimino este comentario y escribo la respuesta.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, @AlexBcn! Mira que me repasé la lista de preguntas frecuentes y no la vi, se ve que lo hice demasiado rápido...

Comment: ¿Y si el sustantivo es femenino? Ejemplo: Naciones miembro o Naciones miembros o naciones miembras.

Comment: @RedtubeFan *Miembro* no cambia de terminación con el género (http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=PDfN5jE, séptima acepción).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No siempre tiene que haber "**la**" forma correcta de decir algo. Me refiero a que en este caso considero que las dos formas son correctas. Considero que se pueden usar ambas.

No obstante a lo anterior (mi opinión), seguí la sugerencia de @CarlosAlejo, y como bien dice él y @AlexBcn, [en la RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas) se explica esto:

Esta situación ocurre en los casos en que una unidad léxica está formada por dos sustantivos, donde el segundo actúa como si fuera un adjetivo para modificar el primero.

En estos casos **normalmente** el primero es el único que suele llevar la marca de **plural**: *países miembro*.

Pero hay casos en que el segundo sustantivo puede adquirir un funcionamiento plenamente adjetivo y adoptar también la marca de plural, como es característico en esta clase de palabras: *países miembros*.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Efectivamente, tras leer el comentario de @AlexBcn y visitar la web de la RAE, me di cuenta de ello. Si quieres, puedes ampliar y documentar tu respuesta con la información contenida allí, para que te quede más redonda.