# ¿Cómo se escriben las palabras compuestas cuando se les añade un sufijo?

Tags: ortografía, sufijos

El otro día leía una cosa así como:

> El Barça tiene **dependencia de Leo Messi**.

Dicho de otra forma, es frecuente leer:

> El Barça tiene **Messidependencia**

(por ejemplo, [Luis Enrique admite que el Barça tiene 'Messidependencia'](http://www.20minutos.es/deportes/noticia/luis-enrique-admite-barca-messi-dependencia-2972040/0/)).

Tras lo cual me surge la duda: ¿cómo se escribiría la palabra si se quisiera incluir también el nombre propio *Leo* en la formación de *Messidependencia*? ¿Sería *Leo Messidependencia*? ¿Sería *Leo-Messidependencia*?

Es decir, ¿cómo se escriben los sustantivos compuestos generados a partir de la inclusión de un sufijo del tipo *dependencia*, *manía* o cualquier otro?

Estuve mirando en el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas pero no encontré demasiada información al respecto de los sufijos, aparte de lo que describen en un artículo sobre género.

Comment: Tú sí que sabes rizar el rizo... :-D Espera que te ayudo: ¿y si el sustantivo puede ir en plural? ¿Cómo se transformaría "dependencia de los países miembro"? ¿Sería _paismiembrodependencia_ o _paisesmiembro(s)dependencia_? Esto suena ya más a alemán que a español...

Comment: y si además hay un prefijo involucrado, como tener (post | auto | inter | bi) pais(-?)miembrodependencia, afecta al uso o no del guión? ;-P

Comment: @Diego ¿y si fuera femenino sería [_paismiembradependencia_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/pa%c3%adses-miembro-o-pa%c3%adses-miembros#comment33173_17474)? :-D

Comment: Para ayudar yo también, debo decir que hay precedentes con palabras técnicas p. ej. esternocleidomastoideo —Creo que son cuatro raices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buscando por sufijo no vas a encontrar mucho, porque "dependencia", "manía" etc. no son sufijos realmente. Pero buscando por "palabras compuestas", sí que podemos encontrar pistas sobre el [criterio de la RAE al respecto](http://www.rae.es/publicaciones/210-derivados-y-compuestos):

> **2.10. Derivados y compuestos**
>   Todas las voces derivadas de otras o formadas mediante composición, sin tener en cuenta la posibilidad de que su significado sea claramente deducible a partir de los elementos que las constituyen, pueden entrar a formar parte del Diccionario. Así sucede con los adverbios terminados en **-mente**, las voces que contienen los prefijos **anti-**, **des-**, etc. Podrá objetarse que las posibilidades de formación de nuevas palabras mediante estos procedimientos son prácticamente infinitas; pero lo cierto es que el uso real, en España y en América, acepta solo algunos neologismos de este tipo, mientras que rechaza otros. En este Diccionario solo aparecen aquellos términos que, vista la documentación de su empleo real, el Pleno académico ha decidido incluir. De igual modo, **para registrar los adjetivos derivados, mediante sufijos no siempre iguales, de nombres propios de persona** (p. ej., **cervantino**, ***valleinclanesco***, **borgiano**, **brechtiano**...) se juzga suficiente el aval académico a partir de la documentación escrita.

De lo anterior sacamos en limpio dos cosas:

- que, respondiendo a tu pregunta y tomando como referencia el adjetivo *valleinclanesco*, lo "correcto" sería **leomessidependencia**;
- que difícilmente la RAE va a aceptar ese palabro :-D