# ¿Cuál es el plural adecuado de 'martín pescador'?

Tags: sustantivos, plurales, compuestos

Leyendo hoy *Las mil y una noches*, veía como se referían a unos "**martín-pescadores**". Al revisar en el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*, indican que el plural debe ir en el primer sustantivo, en cuyo caso serían "**martines pescador**", aunque a continuación dan a entender que es posible usar ambos sustantivos con plural, si el segundo sustantivo es atributo del primero (que pareciera el caso adecuado en este), siendo pues "**martines pescadores**".

¿Cuál de los 3 sería el adecuado? ¿O puede usarse cualquiera?

Comment: También sobre plurales: [¿“Países miembro” o “países miembros”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17474/5481)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pesar de que hoy día se supone que la base es el sustantivo *martín* (tal como está [recogida en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OVHbGKD)), por lo que *martines pescadores* debe ser la forma plural siguiendo las reglas normales de hacer plural un sustantivo seguido por adjetivo (*pescador* es, antes que nada, adjetivo, significando *que pesca*).

Si tomamos *pescador* como sustantivo, frente a dos sustantivos, es posible conservar la forma singular de *pescador*, pero como [nota el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i):

> si el segundo sustantivo puede funcionar, con el mismo valor, como atributo del primero en oraciones copulativas, tiende a tomar también la marca de plural

Y como «los martines que son pescadores» tendría sentido, la tendencia sería marcar *pescador* en plural.

No obstante lo anterior, abundan los ejemplos en que *martín* queda en el singular y *pescador* se modifica plural, muchos de ellos ligados con guion.  Este guion parece ser la clave.  Cuando se entiende una combinación de sustantivo y adjetivo como una sola entidad, lo normal es solo marcar el último elemento en plural: *aguafuertes* (y no *aguasfuertes*), *arcoíris* (y no *arcosiris*, aunque sí es válido *arcos iris* de *arco iris*), *altavoces* (y no *altasvoces*).  Aunque lo más común sería escribir como una palabra, como es normal que las combinaciones de dos adjetivos sigan la misma regla de formación pero usando guion, tampoco sería tan raro encontrar un sustantivo ligado con guion a un adjetivo.

Con la notada presencia histórica de un guion, imagino que para [algunos en el pasado](https://books.google.com/books?id=3pfsWLZeRrIC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%22mart%C3%ADn%20pescadores%22&source=bl&ots=5FQ_tr_GV5&sig=xsSebDnfpV5wECk6k8RrBzWuPkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRtu2XkqfZAhUlTd8KHT0pBj8Q6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22mart%C3%ADn%20pescadores%22&f=false) (e incluso, buscando en Google, hoy en día) la combinación de *martín-pescador* se consideraba palabra compuesta y por lo tanto no se pluralizaba el primer elemento.

En fin, se podría defender cualquier de las tres opciones, aunque yo optaría por pluralizar ambas palabras.

Comment: [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/duda-plural-2/) y la [RAE](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/502065589419257857) dicen que el plural es "martines pescadores" pero no dan ninguna explicación del porqué.

Comment: RAE: [Palabras clave o palabras claves, copias pirata o copias piratas](http://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas). "En el primer caso, clave y pirata están funcionando como **sustantivos en aposición** y no adoptan la marca de plural. En el segundo, están funcionando como **adjetivos plenos**" Muy buena esa explicación sobre "pescador" como sustantivo o adjetivo guifa.

Comment: @blonfu yo creo que hoy día lo más recomendable es precisamente lo que dicen.  Pero como hay gente culta que pluraliza solo lo de pescador, creo que debe haber un reconocimiento de que, sea lo válido hoy como sea, antes tenía alguna alguna validez *martin(-)pescadores*

Comment: @guifa, con el plural en la última palabra ¿quedaría *martin-pescadores* o *martín-pescadores*? (me refiero al acento)