# Plural de términos de dos sustantivos: decreto ley

Tags: sustantivos, plurales

Recientemente, entre las muchas noticias de cada día, ha venido surgiendo una polémica en España acerca de la figura legislativa del **decreto**, con sus consiguientes cruces de acusaciones. Los que más se escuchan son tanto **real decreto** como **decreto ley**.

Mi duda surge cuando se utilizan ambas expresiones en plural. En el primer caso no hay duda; es `reales decretos`, puesto que *real* es un adjetivo. Sin embargo, el segundo no lo tengo tan claro. En muchos informativos vienen empleando la expresión `decretos leyes`, mientras que también es habitual escuchar `decretos ley`.

Investigando un poco, la RAE, en [*Palabras clave o palabras claves, copias pirata o copias piratas*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas) sugiere que lo correcto es mantener el singular del segundo (p.ej. ciudades dormitorio), salvo en el caso de que este pueda funcionar como atributo, en cuyo caso son válidas ambas formas (países miembro y países miembros), como ya se apuntó en preguntas similares como [¿"Países miembro" o "países miembros"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/pa%C3%ADses-miembro-o-pa%C3%ADses-miembros).

Así pues, mi pregunta es: **¿Puede funcionar "ley" como atributo, de forma que se pueda decir "decretos leyes", o debe decirse "decretos ley"?**

Comment: Parece que la confusión es grande y se usan ambas por igual: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=decretos%20ley,decretos%20leyes

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @fedorqui en que ambas son -- como dice la explicación de la RAE citada en la pregunta -- posibles y correctas: "decretos ley" (decretos tipo ley) y "decretos leyes" (decretos que son a su vez leyes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es *decretos leyes*, como explica la RAE en el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=decreto%20ley):

> Su plural es *decretos leyes*

Comment: Muchas gracias por t u respuesta, ya pensaba que nadie iba a responder. Me queda la duda de si la RAE indica algún tipo de explicación del por qué.

Comment: Pues no, no la da. Tengo la sospecha de que la razón es que en realidad no es un sustantivo en aposición (del tipo «hombre rana»), sino una coordinación (del tipo «director-presentador»), porque es tan ley como decreto, es decir, combina ambos conceptos. Claro, que entonces debería ir con guion, como de hecho se solía escribir hace años.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Muy interesante. Efectivamente, yo también habría esperado un guión ahí. Al no haberlo, siempre había pensado que eran "decretos de tipo ley", como apunta @Gustavson en su comentario.